# Creating a new element in an json object using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Is there a way to create a new element in an existing json object using jq? Example below:

Let's say I have this json object and would like to add a new element to foo:

```
json='{
  "id": "<id>>",
  "name": "<name>",
  "properties": {
    "State": "<state>",
    "requests": [],
    "foo": [
      {
        "id": "<id1>",
        "bar1": [
          {
            "baz1": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "<id2>",
        "bar2": [
          {
            "baz2": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

This command works to do that:

```
json2=$($json1 | jq '.properties.foo += [ { "id": "<id3>", "bar3": [ { "baz3": "*"} ] } ]')
```

However, running that same command without a preexisting foo element fails (example array below):

```
json3='{
  "id": "<id>>",
  "name": "<name>",
  "properties": {
    "State": "<state>",
    "requests": []
  }
}'
```

Is there a way in jq to create that element in the json object if one already does not exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Calling a json object an array is really confusing.

Comment: What version of `jq` are you using? I cannot reproduce in `jq` 1.6; the `foo` key in `properties` is created if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your jq program, which can be seen by running:

```
jq '.properties.foo += [ { "id": "<id3>", "bar3": [ { "baz3": "*"} ] } ]' <<< "$json3"
```

It looks like the problem is with your invocation but since it's not clear what $json1 is, I'll just guess that the above is sufficient for you to resolve the issue.